# How can I import video from my JVC Everio HDD video camera to 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, video, camera

What is the best method for importing video from my JVC Everio HDD video camera into Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: Jimmy please see updated answer - let us know if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and cd into the directory that contains the mount point for the camcorder. In my case this was `/media/EVERIO_HDD`

The video files are nested a little deeper in `SD_VIDEO/PRG001`
(e.g. cd /media/EVERIO_HDD/SD_VIDEO/PRG001)

This folder contains two types of files ending in .mod and .moi. We only need the .mod files as these are the actual videos.
To copy them from the camcorder to your hard drive use something along the line of:

`mkdir /home/my_vids/downloaded_INSERT DATE HERE`

`cp -p *.MOD /home/my_vids/downloaded_INSERT DATE HERE/`

This can take a while as the files can be quite large. Note that the -p option tells the cp command to preserve the file timetamps, which will have been set by the camcorder when the recording was made.

If you prefer the files to have a suffix of .mpg instead of .MOD. Run the following rename command from within your downloaded folder to convert them.

`cd /home/my_vids/downloaded_2009-03-01
rename 's/.MOD$/.mpg/' *.MOD`

And that's about it. You will still need to delete them from the camcorder (best done from the camcorder menu). Also remember to keep backups...

Reference link [here](http://www.linuxinstead.com/blog/2009/03/01/copying-jvc-everio-hdd-camcorder-recordings-with-linux/)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use nautilus to copy it over directly. Navigate to the video file on your camera, hit F3 for another pane in nautilus, navigate to where you want it, drag and drop the video. You can also check in the software center for editing apps.  Some may have an import function.  Openshot and Pitivi are the only two I can think of.